# AngularJS display only div when string contains

Tags: angularjs, hide, show

How to in AngularJS display only div when in json filename contain for example jpg string?

I have got a list with file in json with .jpg pdf and other stuffs. I display theme by using `ng-repeat` and `filter{filename:'jpg'}`. It's works fine. But how to hide the div when jpg does not exist ?

```
<div>
   <div>JPG FILES</div>
   <ul ng-repeat="">
     <li>name<a href='#'>download</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post your json ?

Comment: hide the li or the div ? what is your model ?

Comment: @sylwester : sorry but no :/ it's look like name -> attachments -> id -> filename

Comment: @ThomasP1988 : hide whole div when string does not contains for example jpg

Comment: Could you show the expression in `ng-repeat`?

Comment: @runTarm ng-repeat="attachments in example.attachments | filter:{file_name:'jpg'}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure what you want, but this will hide the outer div if filtered results is empty.

```
<div ng-hide="filteredResults.length === 0">
   <div>JPG FILES</div>
   <ul ng-repeat="attachment in filteredResults = (example.attachments | filter: {file_name:'jpg'})">
     <li>{{attachment.file_name}}<a href='#'>download</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

something like this ?

```
ng-show="filename == 'jpg'"
```

filename have to be in your scope

in yout controller

```
$scope.filename = "jpg";
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div>
   <div ng-if="hasImage">JPG FILES</div>
   <ul ng-repeat="">
     <li>name<a href='#'>download</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.hasImage = function()
{
   if(yourjsonfile.indexOf("jpg") > -1)
    {
       return true;
    }else
    {
       return false;
      }

  }
```

Comment: Okey when I add this to my code it isn't display div even when jpg exist. Maybe I got a wrong path to my json file but I don't think so becouse other functions works good.

Comment: the file needs to by loaded you can't just put the path to it ie: $scope.yourjsonfile = $http.get('pathtojourjson').then(...check if jpg exist in $scope.yourjsonfile ... I hope that will help if not please post path to your json file